# How to create an odd number of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to create a plotting function that takes as input the number of required plots and plots them using `pylab.subplots` and the `sharex=True` option. If the number of required plots is odd, then I would like to remove the last panel and force the tick labels on the panel right above it. I can't find a way of doing that and using the `sharex=True` option at the same time.  The number of subplots can be quite large (>20).

Here's sample code. In this example I want to force xtick labels when `i=3`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def main():
    n = 5
    nx = 100
    x = np.arange(nx)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        f, axs = plt.subplots(n/2, 2, sharex=True)
    else:
        f, axs = plt.subplots(n/2+1, 2, sharex=True)
    for i in range(n):
        y = np.random.rand(nx)
        if i % 2 == 0:
            axs[i/2, 0].plot(x, y, '-', label='plot '+str(i+1))
            axs[i/2, 0].legend()
        else:
            axs[i/2, 1].plot(x, y, '-', label='plot '+str(i+1))
            axs[i/2, 1].legend()
    if n % 2 != 0:
        f.delaxes(axs[i/2, 1])
    f.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you replace last `if` in your `main` function with this:

```
if n % 2 != 0:
    for l in axs[i/2-1,1].get_xaxis().get_majorticklabels():
        l.set_visible(True)
    f.delaxes(axs[i/2, 1])

f.show()
```

It should do the trick:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Using `delaxes` seems inefficient when dealing with a large number of axes objects (subplots). I ended up doing this with `add_subplot` instead. But I'm not sure how to acquire the `sharex` or `sharey` that's available with `subplots`.

Answer (score 49):

To put it simply you make your subplots call for an even number (in this case 6 plots):

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(12, 15))
```

Then you delete the one you don't need:

```
f.delaxes(ax[2,1]) # The indexing is zero-based here
```

This question and response are looking at this in an automated fashion but I thought it worthwhile to post the basic use case here.

Answer (score 5):

I generate an arbitrary number of subplots all the time (sometimes the data leads to 3 subplots, sometimes 13, etc). I wrote a little utility function to stop having to think about it.

The two functions I define are the follows. You can change the stylistic choices to match your preferences.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def choose_subplot_dimensions(k):
    if k < 4:
        return k, 1
    elif k < 11:
        return math.ceil(k/2), 2
    else:
        # I've chosen to have a maximum of 3 columns
        return math.ceil(k/3), 3


def generate_subplots(k, row_wise=False):
    nrow, ncol = choose_subplot_dimensions(k)
    # Choose your share X and share Y parameters as you wish:
    figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol,
                                sharex=True,
                                sharey=False)

    # Check if it's an array. If there's only one plot, it's just an Axes obj
    if not isinstance(axes, np.ndarray):
        return figure, [axes]
    else:
        # Choose the traversal you'd like: 'F' is col-wise, 'C' is row-wise
        axes = axes.flatten(order=('C' if row_wise else 'F'))

        # Delete any unused axes from the figure, so that they don't show
        # blank x- and y-axis lines
        for idx, ax in enumerate(axes[k:]):
            figure.delaxes(ax)

            # Turn ticks on for the last ax in each column, wherever it lands
            idx_to_turn_on_ticks = idx + k - ncol if row_wise else idx + k - 1
            for tk in axes[idx_to_turn_on_ticks].get_xticklabels():
                tk.set_visible(True)

        axes = axes[:k]
        return figure, axes
```

And here's example usage with 13 subplots:

```
x_variable = list(range(-5, 6))
parameters = list(range(0, 13))

figure, axes = generate_subplots(len(parameters), row_wise=True)
for parameter, ax in zip(parameters, axes):
    ax.plot(x_variable, [x**parameter for x in x_variable])
    ax.set_title(label="y=x^{}".format(parameter))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

Or, switching to column-wise traversal order (`generate_subplots(..., row_wise=False)`) generates:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing calculations in order to detect what subplot needs to be deleted, you can check in what subplot there is nothing printed. You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387825/11764049) for various methods to check if something is plotted on an axis. Using the function [`ax.has_Data()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.has_data.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.has_data) you can simplify your function like this:

```
def main():
    n = 5
    max_width = 2 ##images per row
    height, width = n//max_width +1, max_width
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(height, width, sharex=True)

    for i in range(n):
        nx = 100
        x = np.arange(nx)
        y = np.random.rand(nx)
        ax = axs.flat[i]
        ax.plot(x, y, '-', label='plot '+str(i+1))
        ax.legend(loc="upper right")

    ## access each axes object via axs.flat
    for ax in axs.flat:
        ## check if something was plotted 
        if not bool(ax.has_data()):
            fig.delaxes(ax) ## delete if nothing is plotted in the axes obj

    fig.show()
```

[image]

You can also specify how many images you want using the `n` parameter and how many images per row you desire with `max_width` parameter.

Comment: Excellent answer. Worked fine, and suitable to a dynamic environment when the number of subplots is not known. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

For Python 3, you can delete as below :

```
# I have 5 plots that i want to show in 2 rows. So I do 3 columns. That way i have 6 plots.
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20, 10))

sns.countplot(sales_data['Gender'], order = sales_data['Gender'].value_counts().index, palette = "Set1", ax = axes[0,0])
sns.countplot(sales_data['Age'], order = sales_data['Age'].value_counts().index, palette = "Set1", ax = axes[0,1])
sns.countplot(sales_data['Occupation'], order = sales_data['Occupation'].value_counts().index, palette = "Set1", ax = axes[0,2])
sns.countplot(sales_data['City_Category'], order = sales_data['City_Category'].value_counts().index, palette = "Set1", ax = axes[1,0])
sns.countplot(sales_data['Marital_Status'], order = sales_data['Marital_Status'].value_counts().index, palette = "Set1", ax = axes[1, 1])

# This line will delete the last empty plot
f.delaxes(ax= axes[1,2])
```

Comment: This answer is not useful at all: the code refers to an external module not requested (seaborn) and includes some external data (Gender, Age, etc.) to which the reader has no access. Then this is substantially a repost of the solution proposed by others without any improvement or other original work.